# When moving a feature in QGIS, is there a way to nudge it rather than use the mouse?

Tags: qgis, vector

I need to move a lot of features (polygons) in QGIS to fit a newly Georeferenced scanned map that is slightly asymmetrically distorted. This is fine as it is just to provide a print copy.

I end up having to do multiple moves of each polygon using the mouse until they are in the right place, because it is easy to overshoot.

As in some image manipulation programs is there a way to turn on using the arrow keys, perhaps with `Shift` or `Ctrl`, to nudge a feature in a particular direction?

The arrow keys pan the map even when the `Move Feature(s)` is activated, or the feature selected, with or without, `Shift` or `Ctrl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a "nudge" feature. In situations similar to your use case, however, I have:

1. Selected the feature, then zoomed in significantly to blow up the corner/point I wanted to place precisely, and then used `Move feature` to move at that scale, before zooming out again.
2. Created a utility layer, into which I placed precise points, and then used snapping to move existing objects to the points in the utility layer (which I then deleted).